# Does Mathematica 11 run on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3, and it comes preinstalled with Mathematica 10, I was hoping someone could tell me if installing version 11.0 is possible?

Comment: It will be possible (when 11 is released for the Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Raspbian is technically a version of Linux though no?

Comment: Yes, however the CPU architecture is ARM, so the regular Linux release cannot run on it.

Comment: @ilian Does WRI have a site tracking the latest release for raspbian?

Comment: No, not that I know of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mathematica 11.0.1 has been just released for the Raspberry Pi.

```
$Version

(* "11.0.1 for Linux ARM (32-bit) (January 17, 2017)" *)
```

As usual, one may immediately upgrade via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 3):

Depending upon all things configuration, from the terminal on an aged New Out Of Box Software RPi try

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to upgrade Mathmatica to 11 along with  everything else.

```
 sudo apt-get install wolfram-engine
```

may work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica 11.2 is available on the Raspberry Pi but doesn't seem to automatically update.  But you can console yourself with "sudo apt-get upgrade wolfram-engine"

Comment: I did get the update automatically with a simple `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`. But I am told it's not compatible with Jessie so I upgraded to Stretch first. Are you on Stretch?